# error message when using loop in shell command

Tags: bash, loops, sh, subshell

What I'm doing wrong?

```
unset list
list=("A" "B" "C")
/bin/sh -c "for i in `seq 1 ${#list[@]}` ; do echo $i ; done "
```

it should return:

```
1
2
3
```

instead of:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `2'
```

Comment: Are you sure `sh` is bash? POSIX `sh` does not have arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, the double-quoted string you pass to `/bin/sh` is processed by the shell before calling `sh`. In particular, both the command substitution involving `seq` and the parameter `$i` are expanded. As a result, you get the following (you can confirm by calling `set -x` before running your code):

```
for i in 1
2
3 ; do echo  ; done
```

The newline following 1 is treated as a termination of the sequence that `for` will iterate over. At this point, `sh` will expect the keyword `do`, but it instead sees `2`.

One way to fix this, assuming you really need to pass a string to another instance of the shell, is to tell `seq` to use a different separator (such as a space). You'll need to escape
the dollar sign in `$i` as well so that it is evaluated by the subshell, not the current shell.

```
unset list
list=("A" "B" "C")
/bin/sh -c "for i in `seq -s' ' 1 ${#list[@]}` ; do echo \$i ; done "
```

This will work with `sh`, because the subshell does not see the array, which it would not understand anyway. sudo_O provides a different answer, which involves protecting the entire string passed to `sh`, and including the definition of `list` in that string so that it is visible in the subshell. Note that your `sh` must be a shell such as `bash`, since POSIX `sh` does not support arrays, as pointed out by jordanm.

Comment: Our answers fix this in different ways. I let the `seq` command evaluate in the current shell, so that the sequence `1 2 3` (without newlines) is passed to the subshell. You move the definition of `list` into the subshell and perform operations on it there. His original syntax error was caused by the fact that the string he passed to `/bin/[ba]sh` contained embedded newlines, which caused the `for` loop to be parsed incorrectly. Run his original code with `set -x` to see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

@chepner gave you the right answer.

By the way, you can also shorten up the command like this (no further shell involved)

```
unset list
list=("A" "B" "C")
for i in `seq 1 ${#list[@]}` ; do echo $i ; done
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP has a good reason for passing the command to a subshell, but this is definitely simpler.

Comment: If your in current shell you don't need to worry about newlines so just can drop the `-s\`

Answer (score 0):

The array `list` will not be defined when you spawn the subshell so it will have no length making:

```
for i in `seq 1 ${#list[@]}`
```

seen as:

```
for i in seq 1 0
```

See:

```
$ sh -c 'echo ${#list[@]}'
0
```

and `seq 1 0` produces no output hence seeing no results.

Either set `list` and print out each value in the current shell:

```
$ list=("A" "B" "C")

$ for i in `seq 1 ${#list[@]}`;do echo $i;done
1
2
3
```

Or define the `list` in the subshell:

```
$ sh -c 'list=("A" "B" "C");for i in `seq 1 ${#list[@]}`;do echo $i;done'
1
2
3
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. As stated, he wants to know why he doesn't see '1 2 3', not 'A B C'.

Comment: @chepner you clearly misunderstood the point printing `A B C` instead of `1 2 3` doesn't make the answer wrong. I have made it explicit now.

Comment: His question was about getting a syntax error, not how to print 'A B C'. Before the edit, this did not answer that question.

Comment: @chepner Before the edit the point was *(and still is)* that the variable would not be defined in the subshell, this is the real issue here.

Comment: It didn't need to be defined in the subshell. He isn't actually using the contents of the list, he just needed the length, which could be evaluated before the subshell is called. With your edits, I have actually upvoted your answer.

Comment: Of course it doesn't need to be defined in the subshell. My answer explains the issue with variables and subshell which is significantly more beneficial to the OP to know what is actually going on and not just a hack to get it working. It's a shame that upvotes begat upvotes and downvotes begat downvotes regardless or an answers correctness/quality.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25781/discussion-between-chepner-and-sudo-o)